# Tbl not grouping 2 same strings

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(purrr)

setwd("path")
file.list <- dir(pattern = "txt$")

Data_cleaner <- function(x) {
  lines <- read_lines(x)
  lower_lines <- tolower(lines)
  natures_df <-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(lower_lines, "(?<=\\dx) | for ", perl = TRUE)))
  
  natures_df_clean <-
    natures_df %>% 
    rename(
      Quantity_dirty = V1,
      Product = V2,
      price_each = V3
    )
  
  Quantity_chr <-
    gsub(
      x = natures_df_clean$Quantity_dirty,
      pattern = "x",
      replacement = ""
    )
  
  Quantity <- as.numeric(Quantity_chr)
  
  price_clean_df <- gsub("R", replacement = "", x = natures_df_clean$price_each)
  
  price_clean <- gsub("each", replacement = "", x = price_clean_df)
  
  Price <- as.numeric(price_clean)
  
  natures_final_df <-
    natures_df_clean %>%
    mutate(
      Price = Price,
      Quantity = Quantity,
      QuantityXPrice = Price * Quantity
    )
  
  Natures <- select(natures_final_df, Product, Quantity)
  Natures
}

df = data.frame()
frame_frame <- map(file.list, Data_cleaner)
Total <- rbindlist(frame_frame)
```

I have been trying to turn text into data frames then join all the data frames, but now I join them and something like "small cucumber" wont' join together so I get 2 instances of something named the same even when I group by, any thoughts?

[image: Data Frame]

This is the text I'm changing and they're all in their own text files

```
2x Small Cucumber for R 10 each
1x Tomatoes 1kg for R 16 each
1x Carrot 1 kg for R 14 each
1x Butter 500g for R 57 each
3x Beef rump steak 300g for R 45 each
2x Chicken Braai pack 1.1kg for R 75 each 
2x Small Cucumber for R 10 each
1x Oyster Mushroom for R 20 each
1x Onions 1 kg for R 15 each
1x Asparagus 200g for R 45 each
1x Strawberry Punnet 250g for R 22 each
2x beef Fillet Steak 300g for R 54 each
1x Chicken flattie lemon and herb for R 85 each
1x Butter 500g for R 57 each
```

P.S I'm new so sorry if its messy.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Comment: check the image I don't want duplicates in the products column that's the expected output.

Comment: Your text file has __two__ lines that start with `2x Small Cucumber`. That's why you get duplicates in your dataframe. Do you want to drop the latter one?

Comment: i want them to collapse into eachother so i get small cucumber 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Final <- Total %>% group_by(Product) %>% summarise(y = sum(Quantity))`

This solved my issue.  I did try `group_by` at first but I didn't `summarise(sum())` the `Quantity` so it didn't collapse all my duplicates together.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hey sorry i was up late and was a bit too lazy to explain but thanks for the reminder.